# Android deprecated tabactivity, when will this no longer work

Tags: android, fragment, tabactivity, android-2.2-froyo

when will the deprecated tabactivity no longer work in future versions of Android? I am asking because Android is open source so someone in the dev community might be lurking here

for designs that I get from clients which mimick iOS style tab-bars, on a Froyo device the tabactivity is the best way to implement this

I'm having much difficulty doing this with fragments with the compatibility pack. see this long question: [Android how to interact with Fragment tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059378/android-how-to-interact-with-fragment-tabs)

so before I switch back to a class TabActivity, when can I expect apps that use tabactivity to no longer work in future android versions?

Comment: I doubt something of the nature of `TabActivity` will ever stop working as it would have huge consequences as it's widely used enough. My guess is it'll just always be depreciated (like `AbsoluteLayout`).

Comment: these are my thoughts, I am looking for a counter opinion too

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly an answer to your question:
With Android 4.0 you will no longer be able to open the menu for a TabActivity unless the device has a hardware menu button. This is because the menu button is no longer there (the buttons on the bottom of the device are soft buttons then with the exception of some devices using hardware buttons). Instead the menu is opened with rightmost widget in the activity's action bar (which TabActivity does not have, because it is no longer supported / modified).